# RxJava2 : Filtering a List<Object> in an Observable

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am very new to Rx programming and I was trying my hands on it in a project. What I want is I am having an object of GamesInfoList as shown below:

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class GameInfoList {
    public static TypeAdapter<GameInfoList> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
        return new AutoValue_GameInfoList.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new AutoValue_GameInfoList.Builder();
    }

    public abstract long id();

    @Nullable
    public abstract String date_added();

    @Nullable
    public abstract String date_last_updated();

    @Nullable
    public abstract GameImages image();

    @Nullable
    public abstract String name();

    @Nullable
    public abstract List<GamePlatformInfo> platforms();

    @AutoValue.Builder
    public abstract static class Builder {

        public abstract Builder id(long id);

        public abstract Builder date_added(String date_added);

        public abstract Builder date_last_updated(String date_last_updated);

        public abstract Builder image(GameImages image);

        public abstract Builder name(String name);

        public abstract Builder platforms(List<GamePlatformInfo> platforms);

        public abstract GameInfoList build();
    }
}
```

Now, I want to load my games by date and name and I wrote a method for that to access this above object in it.

```
public void loadGamesByDateAndName(String date, String name) {
    Timber.d("Load games by date: " + date + " and name: " + name);
    remoteDataHelper
            .getGamesListByDate(date)
            .flatMapObservable(Observable::fromIterable)
            .filter(game -> game.platforms() != null)
            .filter(game -> game.platforms().name().contains(name))
            .toList()
            .subscribe(getObserverFiltered(name, false));
}
```

Here, I am filtering (using filter() operator) the platforms object based on the name inputted in this method. The above method is showing me an error because platform is of type List. How can I filter through the list to match the name and display in my Android app? What changes need to be made to the above method in order to load data by date and name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to iterate inside the second `filter` operator.

```
public void loadGamesByDateAndName(String date, String name) {
    Timber.d("Load games by date: " + date + " and name: " + name);
    remoteDataHelper
            .getGamesListByDate(date)
            .flatMapObservable(Observable::fromIterable)
            .filter(game -> game.platforms() != null)
            .filter(game -> { for(GamePlatformInfo platform : game.platforms()){
                                  if(platform.name().contains(name)) {
                                      return true;
                                  }
                              }
                              return false;
                    }
            )
            .toList()
            .subscribe(getObserverFiltered(name, false));
}
```

Comment: I guess this should work just fine and hence, I will accept this answer. Will test it once. Thanks a lot!!! :-)

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is best. Probably you can build something more RXy and clever, but in the end it'll just be more difficult to understand for the next person that reads it. Or for you a month later ;)

Comment: Yeah I guess so. The operators are so difficult to keep in mind. Need to use them in lot of projects I presume.

Comment: Lol, why the unaccept 3 years later? Is there a better way? If so, please post as answer, I will gladly upvote.

Comment: Apologies @kenny_k it was by mistake I guess. Reaccepting it again.

Answer (score -1):

Well You need to override `equals()` method in `GamePlatformInfo` class.

I assume you have following class definition of `GamePlatformInfo` class:

```
class GamePlatformInfo{
    String name;
    ...
    ...

    public GamePlatformInfo(String name){
        this.name = name;
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof GamePlatformInfo)) return false;
        final GamePlatformInfo other = (GamePlatformInfo)o;
        return name.equals(other.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you just need to to use `contains()` operator to search through that list.
Check following modified snippet:

```
public void loadGamesByDateAndName(String date, String name) {
    Timber.d("Load games by date: " + date + " and name: " + name);
    remoteDataHelper 
            .getGamesListByDate(date) 
            .flatMapObservable(Observable::fromIterable) 
            .filter(game -> game.platforms() != null) 
            .filter(game -> game.platforms().contains(new GamePlatformInfo(name))) // This is all you need to do to search through the list.
            .toList() 
            .subscribe(getObserverFiltered(name, false));
}
```

Under the hood: If you create a list of a class that overrides `equals()` method then `list.contains()` method uses given equals definition to compare items of list.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is incorrect. `List#contains` works using the class's `equals` method, not `compareTo`, as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)). And overriding `equals` of your class just for this use case is a really bad idea, as it will likely cause problems in other places.

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer you are right. `Comparable` is used for sorting I have corrected answer. Overriding equals is not a bad idea. if you implement it properly it wont break anything. Have a look at `equals()` implementation. Even it comes in best practices when using lists, not blindly iterating though list using for loop.

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer in RxJava, it is not best practice to break `Observable` chain that you have done to search in list. I am not saying you are wrong but this is how idiomatic code should be written. no offence, thanks for understanding.

Comment: Overriding `equals` can be [risky business](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265637/356629) if you're not careful - which the answer still isn't, as it doesn't override `hashCode`, which is a _must_ if overriding `equals`. Also, in so doing, you are imposing certain rules for the usage of the object for your entire system, just to facilitate a single use case, which, in my opinion can come back to haunt you. For example if that object ends up making its way into any ORM or other serialization libraries, etc.

Comment: Also, if you see an issue with my answer, please comment there directly, I'm happy to have a discussion about it, just so we can keep the threads from tangling :)

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer thanks to bring it to my attention.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @chandil03